# Is it possible to do this pagination without backgrid?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination, backgrid, backbone.paginator

I'm trying to implement server side pagination like [datetable](https://datatables.net/) and I found [backbone.paginator library](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator), I don't know if there is something else.

Through their examples they used another library to *help accomplishing this* which is [backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com/) and [its paginator plugin](http://backgridjs.com/ref/extensions/paginator.html)

Is it possible to do this pagination without Backgrid? Could you please *add any example* on this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the paginator plugin? What are you trying to do? Offsite recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @EmileBergeron actually I'm limited to how many libraries I can add to the project, by the way, what is the purpose of using backgrid and how it simplifies the creation of pagination?(should I add this to the question?)

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI Can't you look at the source of `backgrid` and judge yourself whether it's worth implementing by urself or just using the existing library?

Comment: Backgrid and paginator does different things. Backgrid only handles dynamic tabular data, while paginator is just a special collection dealing with paginated endpoint with minimal configuration and parsing.

Comment: I once needed infinite scrolling style pagination of long list where all the loaded items would be rendered, and additional pages (chunks) would be loaded and rendered. I [tried using Paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/issues/344) but it's to focused on rendering a page and it was too much of a pain to work around that. So I rolled my own [infinite collection implementation](https://gist.github.com/emileber/7c3b472fa45d8a208d9a8317bb2f38ae).

Comment: datatables dont use server side pagination. I dont see any ajax request when I paginate

Answer (score 3):

I developed the following code to share with you A JS/php code that do server site pagination and you could change it according to your need and later i may summarize it better.

First make connection to DB and create pagination table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `pagination` (
 `id` INT( 16 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `age` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
 `company` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
  )
```

Second insert 400 same records :

```
   $i=0;
   while ($i< 400){
   $pag="insert into pagination (id,name,age,company) VALUES 
  ('NULL','john','40','google')";
  $excu=$mysqli->query($pag);
   $i++;
       }
```

Then make test.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><head>
 <style>
 #container{overflow-x: hidden;max-width:90%;min-width:90% ;margin: 0 auto;}
 td{max-width:10%;min-width:10%}
 tr,td{border:1px solid black }
 #page{display:inline;border:1px solid black}
 #numb,#numbs{display:none}
.button{background:white}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body >
 <?php $defaultoption ="10";?>
 <div id=container></div><span id=numb></span><span id=numbs><?php echo 
 $defaultoption;?></span>
 <script type=text/javascript  src=js.js></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Then make js.js  :

```
  onload = function (){ 
  var container=document.getElementById("container");
  var table =document.getElementById("numbs").innerHTML;
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

  container.innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
 var button=document.getElementById("button");
 button.children[0].disabled="true";
 button.children[0].style.background="yellow";
             }}  
 xhttp.open("POST", "testa.php", true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("table="+table);
    }      


 function select(){
 var sel =document.getElementById("select");
 var table=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
 var b2 =document.getElementById("numbs");
 b2.innerHTML=table;
 var se = new XMLHttpRequest();
 se.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (se.readyState == 4 && se.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=se.responseText;
  var button=document.getElementById("button");
  button.children[0].disabled="true";
   button.children[0].style.background="yellow";

       }}  
   se.open("POST", "testa.php", true);
   se.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   se.send("table="+table);
   }





   function button(button){
   var b2 =document.getElementById("numbs");
   var b1 =button.innerHTML;
   var numb = document.getElementById("numb"); 
   numb.innerHTML=b1;
   var b= b2.innerHTML; 
   var butt = new XMLHttpRequest();
     butt.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (butt.readyState == 4 && butt.status == 200) {

  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=butt.responseText;
  var d = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  for(i=0;i<d.length;i++){
  if(d[i].innerHTML == numb.innerHTML){d[i].disabled="true";
  d[i].style.background="yellow";
    }}}}

  butt.open("POST", "testa.php", true);
  butt.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   butt.send("b="+b+"&b1="+b1);
  }
```

Make testa.php :

```
  <?php
  $pag="SELECT * FROM pagination ORDER BY id ASC ";
  $exc=$mysqli->query($pag);
  $numrwos =mysqli_num_rows($exc);
  if($_POST['b']){
  $b =$_POST['b'];
  $b1 =$_POST['b1'];
  $max=($b*$b1);
  $m =($b1-1);
  $n =($m*$b);
  $min =($n-1);
  if($numrwos){
  echo "<select id=select onchange=select()><option selected=selected>Show Entries</option>";
  if($numrwos < 11){
  echo "<option>10</option>";
  }elseif($numrwos > 10 && $numrwos < 26){
  echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option>"; }elseif($numrwos > 25 && 
  $numrwos < 51){
  echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option><option>50</option>";}else{
  echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option><option>50</option>
  <option>100</option>";}
  echo "</select><br />";
  echo "<table width=80% id=table>";
  echo "<tr><td width=10%>id</td><td>name</td><td>age</td><td>company</td></tr>";
  $stop="0";
  while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($exc)){
  if($stop > $min && $stop < $max){
  echo "<tr><td>".$result['id']."</td><td>".$result['name']."</td>
  <td>".$result['age']."</td><td>".$result['company']."</td></tr>";
  }else{}
  $stop++;
 }echo "</table><br />";
  echo "<div id=button>";
  $i=0;
  while($i < $numrwos){
  $page+=$i % $b == $b-1;
  $i++;
  if($i%$b == 1){
  $pagenum=$page+1;
  echo "<button class=button onmouseover='button(this)'>".$pagenum."</button>";}}
 echo "</div>";
 }else{echo "no records";}

 }else{
 $t =$_POST["table"];
 if($numrwos){
 echo "<select id=select onchange=select()><option selected=selected>Show Entries</option>";
 if($numrwos < 11){
 echo "<option>10</option>";
 }elseif($numrwos > 10 && $numrwos < 26){
 echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option>"; }elseif($numrwos > 25 && $numrwos < 51){
  echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option><option>50</option>";}else{
  echo "<option>10</option><option>25</option><option>50</option>
  <option>100</option>";}
  echo "</select><br />";
  echo"<table width=80% id=table>";
   echo "<tr><td width=10%>id</td><td>name</td><td>age</td><td>company</td></tr>";
  $stop="0";
  while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($exc)){
  echo "<tr><td>".$result['id']."</td><td>".$result['name']."</td>
   <td>".$result['age']."</td><td>".$result['company']."</td></tr>";
  if($stop ==$t-1){break;}
  $stop++;
  }echo "</table><br />";
  echo "<div id=button>";
  $i=0;
  while($i < $numrwos){
  $page+=$i % $t == $t-1;
   $i++;
  if($i%$t == 1){
  $pagenum=$page+1;
   echo "<button class=button onmouseover='button(this)'>".$pagenum."</button>";}}
 echo "</div>";
  }else{echo "no records";}
  } 
  ?>
```

I wish that help you .

Answer (score 0):

I did it

in the `View initialize` function

I call

```
this.reloadCustomPages();
```

here its implementation

```
reloadCustomPages: function(options) {
    var self = this;
    self.block();
    self.customPages.fetch({data: $.param(options)}).always(function () {
        self.unblock();
    });
}
```

in the server side (java spring) I modified the api to accept new query strings

```
@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", defaultValue = "1"),
@RequestParam(value = "perPage", defaultValue = "10")
```

and instead of returning the list directly it returns useful pagination info like

- total number of items in database
- current page nuber
- page size
- and the items itself

check this server-side snippet (I know it's not related but worthy to look at)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editor/pages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void listPages(@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", defaultValue = "1") Integer pageNumber,
                          @RequestParam(value = "perPage", defaultValue = "10") Integer perPage,
                          HttpServletResponse httpResp) throws IOException {

    Long recordsTotal = pageSvc.findTotalNumberOfPages();// select count(*) from table_name    
    List<PbCustomPage> pages = pageSvc.findPages(pageNumber, perPage);// server side query that gets a pagenated data 

    BackbonePaginatorResponse response = new BackbonePaginatorResponse();// I created this simple class 
    response.setTotalCount(recordsTotal);
    response.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
    response.setPerPage(perPage);
    response.setItems(pages);

    httpResp.setContentType("application/json");
    json.createCustomPageSerializer().addProperties().serialize(response, httpResp.getWriter());// just make your server send that obkect
}
```

now back the function call it will till the server to get page 1 with a page size of 10

in my template, I have this

```
<div class="pagination clear" style="text-align: center;">
    <%= customPages.paginationHtml %>
</div>
```

let me tell you how I populate it

```
customPages.paginationHtml = this.generatePagination(customPages);
```

and here is the most important part

```
generatePagination: function (paginationResponse) {
    var currentPage = paginationResponse.pageNumber,
        lastPage = paginationResponse.totalCount==0?1:Math.ceil(paginationResponse.totalCount/paginationResponse.perPage);
    var html = '<ul class="pagination">';
    html += '<li class="'+(currentPage == 1?"disabled":"")+'" data-pb-page-number="1"><a href="#" class="first">&laquo;&laquo;</a></li>';
    html += '<li class="'+(currentPage == 1?"disabled":"")+'" data-pb-page-number="'+(currentPage==1?1:currentPage-1)+'"><a href="#" class="prev">&laquo;</a></li>';


    for (var i = 1; i <= lastPage; i++) {
         html += '<li class="'+(currentPage == i?"active":"")+'" data-pb-page-number="'+i+'"><a href="#" class="page">'+ i +'</a></li>';
    }

    html += '<li class="'+(lastPage == currentPage?"disabled":"")+'" data-pb-page-number="'+(currentPage==lastPage?lastPage:currentPage+1)+'"><a href="#" class="next">&raquo;</a></li>';
    html += '<li class="'+(lastPage == currentPage?"disabled":"")+'" data-pb-page-number="'+(lastPage)+'"><a href="#" class="last">&raquo;&raquo;</a></li>';

    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
},
```

each li I create it has `data-pb-page-number` to be used later

one more thing, how to make new requests to other pages

in the `View initialize` function

```
this.el.on('click', 'ul.pagination li:not(.disabled,.active)', this.getCustomPagesPagination);
```

here its implementation

```
getCustomPagesPagination: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(e.target).closest("li");
    this.reloadCustomPages({pageNumber:$el.data("pb-page-number")})
},
```

the the result is like this

[image]

this how I solved my problem but the question still not answered